# Make slideshow fit into a grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a grid, where I would like the big column `sbp-item1`to contain a slidehow. I am struggeling to figure out how I place that slideshow, so the sliders will keep inside of `sbp-item1`, and fill out the column in the height and width without any padding.

At the moment the slideshow are floating over the `sbp-item1`, and the height and width is not filling out the `sbp-item1`, but going more out of the that column.  Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this, so I keep the slideshow height and width to fit `sbp-item1`?

[A demo fiddle can be seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhwvmg0p/).

Best regards.

```css
<style>
<!--slider-->
.jk-slider{
    width:100%;
}
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}
/* CSS GRID */
.sbp-wrapper {
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
            grid-gap: 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 8px solid #fff;
        } 
.sbp-wrapper > div {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sbp-wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.bg-img {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.sbp-item1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1/9;
    height: 520px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;

}
.sbp-item2 {
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 9/13;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url("https://placehold.it/380x250");
    background-position: 90% 10%
}
.sbp-item3 {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 9/13;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url("https://placehold.it/380x250");
} 
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .sbp-item1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1/13;
    height: 520px;
    }
    .sbp-item2 {
    grid-row: 3 / 3;
    grid-column: 1/13;
    height: 200px;
    }
    .sbp-item3 {
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    grid-column: 1 / 7;
    height: 200px;
    } 
</style>
```

```html
<div class="sbp-wrapper">
    <div class="sbp-item1 bg-img">
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/800/520" /></a>
                    <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Search for</h1>        
                        <h3>the books you need and save ! </h3>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</p>
                    </hgroup>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/800/520" /></a>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Search for</h1>        
                        <h3>the books you need and save ! </h3>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</p>
                    </hgroup>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://placekitten.com/800/520" /></a>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Search for</h1>        
                        <h3>the books you need and save ! </h3>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</p>
                    </hgroup>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="sbp-item2 bg-img" href="#"></a>
    <a class="sbp-item3 bg-img" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW `hgroup` is an obsolete element under HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So I should change that to a `div` tag instead? When I look the layout on mobile it is looking horrible.

Comment: That's up to you. An hgroup was more of a layout notation rather than a specific element thing so a div would work.